# PHP newbie- specific scenario on how to parse an XML value stored in a variable using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to parse an XML data stored in a variable, using Simple XML.

THis is the data I am talking about:

```
<SearchResults:searchresults xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd /vstatic/ae1bf8a790b67ef2e902d2bc04046f02/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd">
    <request>
        <address>2114 Bigelow Ave</address>
        <citystatezip>Seattle, WA</citystatezip>
    </request>
    <message>
        <text>Request successfully processed</text>
        <code>0</code>
    </message>
    <response>
        <results>
            <result>
                <zpid>48749425</zpid>
                <links>
                    <homedetails>http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2114-Bigelow-Ave-N-Seattle-WA-98109/48749425_zpid/</homedetails>
                    <graphsanddata>http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/charts/48749425_zpid,1year_chartDuration/?cbt=7522682882544325802%7E9%7EY2EzX18jtvYTCel5PgJtPY1pmDDLxGDZXzsfRy49lJvCnZ4bh7Fi9w**</graphsanddata>
                    <mapthishome>http://www.zillow.com/homes/map/48749425_zpid/</mapthishome>
                    <comparables>http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/48749425_zpid/</comparables>
                </links>
                <address>
                    <street>2114 Bigelow Ave N</street>
                    <zipcode>98109</zipcode>
                    <city>Seattle</city>
                    <state>WA</state>
                    <latitude>47.63793</latitude>
                    <longitude>-122.347936</longitude>
                </address>
                <zestimate>
                    <amount currency="USD">1219500</amount>
                    <last-updated>11/03/2009</last-updated>
                    <oneWeekChange deprecated="true"/>
                    <valueChange duration="30" currency="USD">-41500</valueChange>
                    <valuationRange>
                        <low currency="USD">1024380</low>
                        <high currency="USD">1378035</high>
                    </valuationRange>
                    <percentile>0</percentile>
                </zestimate>
                <localRealEstate>
                    <region id="271856" type="neighborhood" name="East Queen Anne">
                        <zindexValue>525,397</zindexValue>
                        <zindexOneYearChange>-0.144</zindexOneYearChange>
                        <links>
                            <overview>http://www.zillow.com/local-info/WA-Seattle/East-Queen-Anne/r_271856/</overview>
                            <forSaleByOwner>http://www.zillow.com/homes/fsbo/East-Queen-Anne-Seattle-WA/</forSaleByOwner>
                            <forSale>http://www.zillow.com/east-queen-anne-seattle-wa/</forSale>
                        </links>
                    </region>
                    <region id="16037" type="city" name="Seattle">
                        <zindexValue>381,764</zindexValue>
                        <zindexOneYearChange>-0.074</zindexOneYearChange>
                        <links>
                            <overview>http://www.zillow.com/local-info/WA-Seattle/r_16037/</overview>
                            <forSaleByOwner>http://www.zillow.com/homes/fsbo/Seattle-WA/</forSaleByOwner>
                            <forSale>http://www.zillow.com/seattle-wa/</forSale>
                        </links>
                    </region>
                    <region id="59" type="state" name="Washington">
                        <zindexValue>263,278</zindexValue>
                        <zindexOneYearChange>-0.066</zindexOneYearChange>
                        <links>
                            <overview>http://www.zillow.com/local-info/WA-home-value/r_59/</overview>
                            <forSaleByOwner>http://www.zillow.com/homes/fsbo/WA/</forSaleByOwner>
                            <forSale>http://www.zillow.com/wa/</forSale>
                        </links>
                    </region>
                </localRealEstate>
            </result>
        </results>
    </response>
</SearchResults:searchresults>
```

Now the above type of XML is stored in variable named `$zillow_data`

First I load it using SimpleXML using the code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($zillow_data);
```

Now, I want to get the "message" value as shown in the XML data above.

When I try

```
foreach($xml->message[0]->text[0] as $response)
```

It does not work.

When I try something like the below code I get an error in Netbeans IDE

```
foreach($xml->SearchResults:searchresults[0]->message[0]->text[0] as $response)
```

The error I get is "unexpected : "

How do I correctly fetch the message in above XML data?

Also how do I parse through all the "result" elements, one by one?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete, valid XML example?

Comment: Give valid xml, you should use getNamespaces() function

Comment: @Arvind, your XML is not valid, when loading it with SimpleXMLElement it throws `namespace error : Namespace prefix SearchResults on searchresults is not defined`. Can you fix that?

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro The word "SearchResults" is only used at the start and end of XML response- I think this may be related to the fact that there is a ":" in <SearchResults:searchresults  -- in any case kindly let me know how to parse "<SearchResults:searchresults " because when I try xml->ELEMENT_NAME with the ":" it gives an error? Thanks

Comment: Your XML has *errors*, you could say it is *invalid*. Therefore a parser does not *precisely* know what to do with it, hence it can *disappear* or *change* (albeit this is a grey-area as it was invalid in the first place, so you can't change wrong into right, so wrong is probably "changed" into wrong): http://eval.in/32925 - output it to see what exactly simplexml will read here. ***Then*** decide how to access an element.

Comment: @hakre this is not a dupe of the question you have linked to-- for some reason the sample XML at the API site (from where I am getting + processing this data) is not correct-- but when I ran the solution as suggested by shadyyx it worked perfectly... Arvind.

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro for some reason the data sample given at the API provider is not correct -- I ran the code given by shadyyx and was able to process the runtime XML successfully:) Thanks anyway for your help:) Arvind.

Comment: well, actually as I already *commented* if you look into the XML first before accessing it then it should work. You confirm that by saying the code by shadyyx works. That is just that SimpleXMLElement works as documented. The link to the other question suggests the same way of just works, it also additionally shows how you can add the missing declaration *your own*. As it's about the same error, offers an explanation and explains a solution and has an answer, it's a perfect duplicate. You just have *confirmed* that by saying shadyyx code works.

Comment: @hakre you are partially correct- my XML sample is also incorrect as in the other question- as the structure of XML in my question is different I cannot obtain a solution by looking at that question(which I understood/obtained only after reading shadyyx's code)

Comment: And that is why it is so important to have both question linked together as possible duplicates. So that a new user having the same problem can see both solutions. Also shadyyx can move the answer over to the duplicate (or a moderator can do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You use the code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

while the `$string` variable contains the XML, the first element `<SearchResults:searchresults>` becomes the main `$xml` SimpleXMLElement object, while the child tags `<request>`, `<message>` and `<response>` are its properties.

Thus, forgetting about the `undefined namespace` warnings, You should be able to do e.g.:

```
foreach($xml->response->results->result as $result) {
    echo (string) $result->zpid;
}
```

There is only one `message` with only one `text` element, thus if You want to echo this one, You should only do:

```
echo (string) $xml->message->text;
```

Do a `var_dump($xml);` to understand the XML structure being transformed into objects and arrays after loading it with SimpleXML.

Comment: @shadyx your code is correct- there is just one (small) error--> please put "->result" after "->results in the foreach loop code-- then I will accept your answer as the right answer. Thanks, Arvind

Comment: @Arvind Added, probably forgot to put it there first time ;-) Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I understood that it was a typo:) just pointed out so that others who see this and are struggling with simpleXML/php (like me:) ) understand it correctly:) Thanks a lot, Arvind.